# Water pressure generates heat?

Tags: science-based, technology, shipbuilding, endothermic-reaction

Assuming an infinite supply of water at significant pressure. The city is situated underneath a large sea.

If some of the water is allowed to depressurize using a pipe of increasing diameter, what thermal effect would this have? Would heat be generated?

The city is a water tight unit at surface air pressure, and is carved into the sea floor.

Comment: you can't depressurize the water if you are still under water

Comment: Not to mention that liquid water changes its volume very little when under pressure. Liquids are not gases.

Comment: You should use a pipe to the surface, then the water at the top will evaporate into the atmosphere, creating a lower pressure in the bottom of the pipe compared to the ambient hydrostatic pressure. That pressure difference can be used to extract work.

Comment: My city is at surface air pressure. Assume there are lots of unobstructed air pipes connecting city to air above sea

Comment: @ken if you open a pipe to the water than the water will flood your city in that case

Comment: Yes, but i have valves and stuff

Comment: This question seems to be better suited for physics.se

Comment: Assume I have a separate way of getting rid of excess water

Comment: Why do you want heat? just use turbine to generate electricity, that will give you direct heat source (inefficiency in the turbine) plus electricity to generate as much heat as you want.

Comment: You won't have anyway to get rid of excess water unless you have some place that is also deep below the sea, because if you have to pump the water up to the surface, you lose more energy than you gain from using the pressurized sea water above your city. Empty deep caverns are hard to find and limited in size, water tables are pressurized.

Comment: By the way, using that water will gradually flood your city, if you're city is under the water and not using pumps.

Comment: I agree that this should be on Physics.SE.  It's a pure physics problem.  However, when it does get migrated, I recommend changing "infinite supply" to "unlimited supply" or "unbounded supply."  "Infinite" is a word which has a very precise meaning in physics, and it's not quite the meaning you intend here.  Changing that word will decrease the likelihood of the question getting derailed once it gets to Physics.SE

Comment: Water under pressure has a lot of potential energy. As it goes to the area of lesser pressure, it would speed up, according to Bernoulli's principle. If you slow it down by friction, that kinetic energy would turn into heat.

The problem is that a liter of water under 1 atm has energy of 100 J - enough to heat to up to 0.025 degrees. To heat up water to meager 10 degrees you need 400 atm - pressure that is quite hard to handle, so it is better to make water to rotate generator and use electricity to heat up things.

Comment: You maybe thinking of Ocean Thermal Energy Conversion (OTEC). "Ocean thermal energy conversion (OTEC) uses the temperature difference between cooler deep and warmer shallow or surface seawaters to run a heat engine and produce useful work, usually in the form of electricity. OTEC can operate with a very high capacity factor and so can operate in "base load" mode." Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_thermal_energy_conversion This may answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question, the act of depressurizing anything causes [cooling](https://www.bre.com/Blog/Keeping-Things-Cool.aspx).  This wouldn't benefit a city at the bottom of a sea as [deep water is cold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_ocean_water).  Building a city on the ocean bottom would likely be done near a [hydrothermal vent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_vent) to capture heat and [generate power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator).

Comment: Using water pressure to compress air could cause heat. Not a reasonable way to get it since you have finite volume though.

Comment: That's true in that the act of pressurizing anything creates heat just as depressurizing causes cold.  However, the *fact* of high pressure doesn't cause heat (or the bottom of oceans would boil).  Using ocean pressure to create heat by compressing air would require decompression in the outside ocean, which is already at or near freezing.  All in all... if it worked at all, it would be very inefficient.